# renderInContext called on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to programatically create an image from the current frame of a MPMoviePlayerController video. I am using renderInContext called upon the player's view.layer however the image that is created is all black with the video player controls, but I am expecting to see the current frame of the video

My code (http://pastie.org/1020066)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(moviePlayer.view.bounds.size);
[moviePlayer.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// I also tried this code (same results)

// moviePlayer is a subview of videoView (UIView object)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(videoView.bounds.size);
[videoView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get a thumbnail of your movie, you should probably check the `thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:` method of MPMoviePlayerController.